# Should we have MathJax?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

We share some ground with [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - according to our on-topic rules - whenever it gets specific to the Pi. As such there are posts out there that could benefit from a readable typesetting of mathematical formulas.

Therefore the question is: **Should we have [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) enabled on our site?**

A discussion should cover the relevance of a typeset mathematical notation for our site in terms of user experience and the question of effort vs. need (e.g. [this old discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106281/mathjax-should-also-work-in-stackoverflow) hints that it is *heavy*).

MathJax of course requires additional formatting by the user. So it is definitely safe to assume that newcomers would need to be helped at this. However, the main use case would not be questions but comprehensive answers. I'd expect that our dedicated personnel giving such answers will pick up the notation in due time (see [basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get a feeling).

Some examples:

- @RPi: [Powering the Pi from battery (power consumption)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39255/powering-the-pi-from-battery-power-consumption/39273#39273) simple formulas **w/o** MathJax, setting them nicely is little more than eye-candy of course

[image: how cool MathJax is]

- @EE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2274/52154 simple in-line sub- and super-scripts as are typical for electrical engineering
- @EE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/153194/52154 real formulas, granted they might be rarely used here (Warning: Post contains cats!)

Comment: How would MathJax work does it require extra formatting by the user? Can you proviide some examples where this would help. how would this interact with source code (which should (I assume not have this applied to it)?

Comment: @SteveRobillard, find your comment addressed in edit and "answer" to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I am not trying to be a jerk, but can you provide some example questions/answers from this site. Ideally with and without MathJax (I realize this may not be possible without having it enabled for the site).

Comment: There you go. Looks cool, does it not? ("This is the mathematical notation you're looking for." "He can go about his business." "Move along.")

Comment: I have one more question, if we enable this and it has negative effects (performance etc.) can we revert back without problems.

Comment: Well. Text bodies will have things like $$something-something$$ in the clear, if reverting back. Nothing that could not be edited out of course. Can we query the data base for a string like "$$" to fix it?

Comment: Adding answers so ppl can vote if needed :) I think the circuit schematic thing would be much more helpful though...

Comment: @Ghanima There's data SE for querying stuff https://data.stackexchange.com/raspberrypi/revision/415506/530422/search-for (involves SQL'ing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem to have wide community support, and the community has questioned the potential value this feature would add. As a result we will not be implementing this feature.

Answer (score 3):

> How would this interact with source code (which should (I assume not have this applied to it))?

Tested that on [EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), seems to not collide with code. Before introduction of the feature this would have to be checked in detail of course.

[image]

Comment: They have code blocks also on EE, they probably would notice...

Comment: @Wilf, so it would seem.

Answer (score 3):

NO, this site is for the Raspberry Pi, not maths :)

Comment: I agree. Schematics would be much more useful. I see some users use paint just to illustrate what they're doing.

Comment: The Mathjax would only work in Questions and Answers - NOT in comments like this?  I am not convinced that working just with HTML and Unicode would be any harder, and that is just as usable - if I have time I am quite happy to refer to an <b>I<sup>2</sup>C bus</b> or point out that V<sub>cc</sub> is <i>4.75.0±0.25 Volts</i> - it is just it doesn't actually work here.

Comment: You also have to allow java-script from mathjax.org to operate which is yet another site to enable if you use [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) and allow cross-site requests to the same site if you use [RedirectPolicy](https://requestpolicycontinued.github.io/) in Mozilla browsers!

Comment: @PandaLion98, I think both techniques have their merrit, and I don't think we have to pick one over the other. We can decide whether we need any or both of them. We'll get to the matter after christmas.

Comment: @SlySven, heavy tagging does not work in the comments either way. But I think that both HTML tags and possibly mathjax are the most helpful in questions and answers only. Not having either in the comments section is only a very minor drawback.

Answer (score 2):

In 45 years working as an Electrical Engineer I have rarely needed mathematical symbols. (I did once write a specification which used matrix algebra to explain the operation — this used Micro$oft equation editor.)

The rest of the time I used standard mathematical notation (as used in FORTRAN), which most engineers can read.

I often use Unicode symbols e.g. Ω μ λ ² ± to make posts more readable but these need no special tools.

The vast bulk of users on raspberrypi.stackexchange seem to have problems with current and voltage. They don't need fancy mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1):

YES, it's brilliant and would be useful here