# Should we have Schematics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, schematic

Because of the Pi's usage in electronics projects, we have a few questions related to connecting the Pi to various circuitry, which occasionally will require diagrams to demonstrate how it could work.

So should we have a (Circuit Labs) Schematics function, similar to those used on EE (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask))?

As far as I remember, I think most users currently do circuit diagrams using codeblocks, vague photos, screenshots of schematic programs (e.g. [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org)).... I gave up trying this on [one question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/how-can-i-send-the-same-pwm-output-to-multiple-connections) and just screenshotted EE's question editor :-/

Also, would this have problems with software licensing etc?

Users on other sites like [Arduino](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12/14982) ([A51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/arduino-stack-features-mathjax-and-circuitlab)), [DIY](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1111/24376) seem to want it as well. It also seems to be available on [Amateur Radio (Beta)](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177/please-add-schematics-to-ham-se).

*[Similar question on MathJax support](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/641/should-we-have-mathjax)*. Also [EE's feature request](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963/29454).

<sup>I thought this had already been asked here (might have been another site), but I couldn't find any questions on it....</sup>

Comment: Chucking in answers so people can vote, if anyone cares...

Comment: Playing devils advocate this would seem to be directed at those above the level of most in our community. It is more than I would expect a noobie to use or understand, which means that it would be of limited use for those answering questions too. For example which diode do I choose? What if any are the differences between these diodes?

Comment: I tested it on EE and would dare to say that it is quite intiutive to use. The diodes example comes up with the setting 1N4148, call it a generic diode if you will. The selection of the component is really separate from drawing of the schematics. Actually it should be the part where EE comes into play.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, as said over there, I hope you don't mind taking [that example](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39189/19949) to make a case **pro schematics editor**. I argue that such schematics could be as easily made in the online editor as used on EE - without leaving the browser, finding some graphics editor, saving and uploading the image... (negative side: we'd loose hand drawn arrows and the certain flair that comes along).

Comment: No I don't mind you using my MS Paint drawing as an example. +1 for pointing out the negative of fancy schematics. You may want to copy my image here and then draw up a schematic for easy side by side comparison.

Comment: @Wilf, *it's active*! See http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/701/we-proudly-present-schematics Since you brought it up, care to write a short introduction? It might just fit well our upcomming blog.

Comment: This was an *excellent* idea, and it's good to have it. The issue now seems to be getting people to **use it**. I've posted [this link](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question/2075#2075) in maybe 100 comments to questions where a schematic would benefit the OP, and AFAIK it has not yielded one schematic addition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YES we should, this would be useful!

<sup>Not sure but we may need examples to prove we need this, plz comment or something if u spot em!</sup>

Comment: MAYBE we do need this for sake of easy-of-use, and it might help with migration to and from EESE if we use the same drawing system however I'm equally likely to upload an image (or potentially even simple files - built using the default component libraries) from the GP Licensed [GEDA](http://www.geda-project.org/) project's gschem schematic drawing program which anyone can access/use - obviously such contributions will fall under the CC-BY-SA terms of this site.

Comment: related: http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-do-i-describe-or-draw-my-circuit-in-such-a-way-that-everybody-understands-wh

Comment: This has been turned on effective immediately.

Answer (score -1):

NO (I like drawing things myself)