# We proudly present: Schematics!

Tags: discussion, user-interface, schematic

Following up on [Should we have Schematics?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/should-we-have-schematics) we can now proudly announce that the embedded Circuit-Lab schematics editor is available for questions and answers at our main site (and meta too).

Just click the new button in the markdown bar and have fun.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic news, this will prove to be valuable for answers and questions alike.

Comment: Sarcasm? ;) Let's try to use it as good as we can. Keep pointing new users to the tool. Who dares to explain the usage - feel free to do so.

Comment: Heheh, no- not sarcasm. You wont believe how many times I wanted to answer with a schematic and decided not, because all the online tools are are a mission. I enjoy this implementation as used on Electronics Exchange. Albeit, a bit late, but better late than never :)

Comment: It would be nice to have something similar for flow charts too.. not sure if there is SE implementation of it though.

Comment: make that a feature request if you like (but don't get greedy). You may also rework all your previous answers :)

Comment: I will have a look at some some frequently visited previous answers, when I get some time.

Comment: related: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2075/19949

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNETin.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure the LED won't damage? LEDs typically operate at 10 mA, don't they? This one is simulated at 30 mA.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Did I mention I was a n00b?

Comment: It's all good. Continuous 30mA, peak 120mA according to the datasheet.

Comment: ... and as long as SW1 remain in this position, it should all be safe.