# How do I add a schematic to my question?

Tags: discussion, schematic

I see some questions and answers here that include schematic drawings. How do I add a schematic to my question (or answer)?

Comment: I posted this Q&A because: 1) several people don't seem to know how to do this [Example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84527/problem-with-adc-mcp3008?noredirect=1#comment134736_84527), and 2) I couldn't find where it was explained in the docs for this forum. May I ask why it was moved here?

Comment: Questions about the site itself, like this one, belong on the meta site, which is a place specifically for questions like this. Any question about how to use the site, our policies or any bugs should be posted on the meta site rather than the main site. The main site is intended for questions about the Pi, so this would be off-topic there. See also: [What's meta?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Ah! OK, that makes sense - thanks. I didn't know if the people who need this information would ever see it here. I had the idea that 'meta' was more like a "teacher's lounge" ha ha :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look **up**! When you are drafting or editing your question or answer, you will see a toolbar with a number of icons at the top of your **Edit** area. The toolbar has several icons: **B** for **Bold**, images, links, lists, etc. There is also an icon for schematics:

[image: the toolbar]

When you click that link (or `Control-m` from the keyboard), an overlay will appear in your browser. This is the online schematic generator supplied by [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/).

Using the schematic generator is easy. Create your schematic by selecting components in the galley on the left side, dropping them the grid area, and connecting them with wires. Once you've completed your schematic, simply click the `Save and Insert` button in the upper right corner. This will embed a "link" to your schematic in your **Edit** area. This link will be rendered as a schematic in your **Preview** area, and embedded in your **Question** once you post it.

If you need help using the tool, [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com) has several resources, including an [online textbook](https://www.circuitlab.com/textbook/) that will get you going. And don't worry too much about minor errors in your schematic as you will be able to edit your schematic: click `edit` below your question, then once your **Edit** area opens, click `edit the above schematic` to reopen your schematic.

This is an incredibly useful tool. If your question involves hardware or wiring, adding a schematic to your question will help others help you by adding clarity and specificity to your question.

Comment: In case anyone gets upset, it is worth observing that while you can use it here for free, CircuitLab requires a paid membership beyond that (which applies if you, e.g., want to convert to PDF via the interface).

Comment: Yes, glad you mentioned that. I suppose if one does a lot of schematics it's worth the price; I couldn't justify it for myself (plus, I'm cheap!)